# Ajustar texto en celdas y Responsive Table con Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

Tengo un problema, que por más simple que pueda llegar a ser, no logro (creo yo) encontrar la forma correcta de formular la pregunta en Google o aquí en Stack, para encontrar la solución que necesito.

Tengo el siguiente código para una tabla:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>OPERAR CON PROVEEDORES</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-hover table-condensed" border="0">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                <th scope="col">CUIT</th>
                <th scope="col">IVA</th>
                <th scope="col">Dirección</th>
                <th scope="col">Número</th>
                <th scope="col">Piso</th>
                <th scope="col">Puerta</th>
                <th scope="col">Ciudad</th>
                <th scope="col">Provincia</th>
                <th scope="col">Código Postal</th>
                <th scope="col">Pais</th>
                <th scope="col">Teléfono</th>
                <th scope="col">Mail</th>
                <th scope="col">Edición</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

El problema es que la información contenida en las celdas hace un salto cuando son dos o más palabras y hay un espacio entre ellas.
Por ejemplo, en `<th>Código Postal</th>`, la palabra "Código" aparece arriba, y "Postal" aparece debajo, en la misma celda.
La idea es que aparezcan una al lado de la otra.

**EDIT1:**
Por otro lado, la tabla me queda demasiado larga y excede el ancho de la pantalla.
Quisiera que la tabla, genere una barra de desplazamiento horizontal y poder leer toda la tabla, y no exceda el ancho de la pantalla.
Espero se entienda.
Gracias!

Comment: El problema es que ese elemento al ser `responsive` siempre 'partirá' las palabras cuando consiga un espacio. Puedes reemplazar el espacio por un `&nbsp;`. Tu elemento quedaría así: `<th scope="col">Código&nbsp;Postal</th>`. Prueba y comentas. Saludos

Comment: Hola!, gracias por tu respuesta. Efectivamente, funciona. El problema es que los otros datos contenidos en las demás celdas van a provenir de una base de datos cuyos textos tienen espacios, por lo que sucede lo mismo. Saludos!

Comment: Jejeje, gracias. Soy muy *old school*, imagino tu cara: ***¿`&nbsp;`? ¿wtf?***. Aún me estoy riendo. XD

Comment: jajaj para nada! de hecho lo uso en un par de lugares en mis páginas, sobre todo en algunos `<label>` que no quiero que tengan nada escrito, pero que necesito que me reconozcan que hay un espacio. Gracias por tu aporte!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar CSS, con la propiedad `white-space` y el atributo `nowrap`. Esta propiedad determina como se va a manejar los espacios en blanco dentro de un elemento. Puedes ver más información en el [MDN de Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

---

Para que aparezca la barra horizontal en tu tabla, debes de poner la clase `.table-responsive` sobre la etiqueta `table`, y no sobre el contenedor `div.col-md-12` por que si no, el contenedor va a heredar todas las propiedades de .table-responsive. Hice la modificación en el código.

```css
th{
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>OPERAR CON PROVEEDORES</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <table class="table table-hover  table-responsive table-condensed" border="0">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                <th scope="col">CUIT</th>
                <th scope="col">IVA</th>
                <th scope="col">Dirección</th>
                <th scope="col">Número</th>
                <th scope="col">Piso</th>
                <th scope="col">Puerta</th>
                <th scope="col">Ciudad</th>
                <th scope="col">Provincia</th>
                <th scope="col">Código Postal</th>
                <th scope="col">Pais</th>
                <th scope="col">Teléfono</th>
                <th scope="col">Mail</th>
                <th scope="col">Edición</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias! he añadido un archivo css con `table{white-space: nowrap;}` y funcionó. de todas maneras, la tabla ahora me queda más grande que la pantalla. Alguna sugerencia para que la tabla, por mas ancha que sea, genere la barra de desplazamiento?

Comment: ¿Podrías actualizar tu pregunta con esto que estas pidiendo? Por favor. @JoseManuelBorras

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta, espero que se entienda y esté bien la edición. Gracias! @Hoose

Comment: ¿No te aparece la barra horizontal? Con la clase .table-responsive, debería de aparecerte. @JoseManuelBorras

Comment: Me aparece cuando achico el navegador, y la barra de desplazamiento aparece en la tabla, pero cuando lo tengo maximizado, la tabla se agranda hasta más allá del límite, y la barra horizontal me la da el navegador. La idea es que el scrool lo tenga en la tabla. Gracias nuevamente. @Hoose

Comment: Hice la modificación, @JoseManuelBorras. Creo que es a lo que te refieres, cualquier duda, aca ando.

Comment: Gracias @Hoose nuevamente! Sin embargo, no me funciona. La clase `table-responsive` no tiene efectos sobre la etiqueta `<table>`, solo funciona sobre el `<div>`. Intenté hacer con otro `<div>` que encierre la tabla, pero tampoco sin el resultado esperado.

Comment: Voy a cerrar esta pregunta aquí. Porque me ha surgido otro problema muy diferente al que estoy teniendo, y de paso voy a editar el título para que se entienda mejor. Gracias por tu aporte @Hoose... Estas respuestas son las que sirven para este problema.